# Maven: Multi module project dependecies not resolved (parent pom)

Tags: java, maven

This is my maven project structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── rep-digital-api
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
└── rep-digital-common
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
```

Parent `./pom.xml` modules declaration is:

```
<groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
<artifactId>rep-digital</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>rep-digital-common</module>
    <module>rep-digital-api</module>
</modules>
```

Then, `rep-digital-common` has `rep-digital` as parent, `./rep-digital-common/pom.xml`:

```
<artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
...
<parent>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

So, `rep-digital-api` has `rep-digital-common` as dependency and `rep-digital` as parent:

```
<artifactId>rep-digital-api</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
...     
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In order to make everything works, I first install `rep-digital-common` using `mvn clean package install` and it seems to be installed correctly on my local repository:

```
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/net/gencat/transversal/repositori/digital/rep-digital-common/
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/  maven-metadata-local.xml
```

However, the problem appears when I'm trying to build `rep-digital-api`. The message is:

> Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

It seems `mvn` is not able to pick up parent pom...

The command I execute is: `mvn clean package` in `./rep-digital-api`

Any ideas?

Comment: What `mvn` command are you running and from which directory?

Comment: The command I execute is: `mvn clean package` in `./rep-digital-api`

Comment: Sounds like there is no `rep-digital` artefact in your `.m2` repository (or remotely). This implies to me that you did not `cd rep-digital; mvn install`. Have you looked inside `.m2` and checked whether you do indeed have the rep-digital artefact installed locally?

Comment: Your setup looks correct, you should just run `mvn clean package` from `rep-digital` (the parent). As the others are modules, they will be built in the order they're listed. If anything is incorrectly declared, the problem will show when building the parent

Comment: run `mvn clean install` on the parent pom

Comment: I've not installed `rep-digital`. Do you mean, I first need to `mvn install` into `./`. What's going to install? only a pom file?

Comment: It will build and install the parent first, then build and install each child module in turn. And yes, it will install the pom (which is the artifact type)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no `rep-digital` artefact in your `.m2` repository (or remotely). This implies to me that you did not `cd rep-digital; mvn install`. You can confirm this by looking inside `.m2` and checking whether you do indeed have the rep-digital artefact installed locally.

Installing the parent `rep-digital` will create:

- an artefact `.m2/repository/net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital/rep-digital/1.0-SNAPSHOT/rep-digital-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`

  - this is just a copy of `rep-digital`'s `pom.xml`
- a few `maven-metadata-local.xml` metadata files describing when each artefact was last updated

Installing the parent artefact will also install all the child artefacts.